# How to change capabilities for each spec in Protractor?

Tags: protractor

I have the following problem:

In my application I have different submenus and I am testing every submenu in an own spec.

For one spec I need to have native events set to true, but for another spec I need to set native events to false. I tried to write in my spec in the first describe:

```js
browser.nativeEvents = false;
```

and tried to switch the setting (default value is true) but it doesn't work. 
I also tried in my spec:

```js
beforeAll(() => { browser.nativeEvents = false });
afterAll(() => { browser.nativeEvents = true });
```

Is there a possibility to change the capability for a spec?

Comment: As I understand, Capabilities are set during the browser creation and cannot be edited on the fly. You need to set up the capabilities you need beforehand, and if you need a custom set, you will need to create a new browser driver and use it in that test.

Comment: Which browser are you using? moreover I don't think that protractor supports nativeEvents.Its more of a selenium webdriver issue, as far as I know Native events are deprecated and deleted from FirefoxDriver.

Comment: I am using IE11. In chrome all the tests are working ok and there are no problems with native events. It's just an IE thing....

Answer (score 0):

I did it in my test cases `waitForAngularEnabled` to true for one spec and false for other. Instead of doing it in `afterAll` You can do it in `beforeAll` of each spec file